# move numbers out of a string?

Tags: python, string, for-loop, while-loop, split

So i'm new in coding and I need to do something like this:
x="rtx2080gtx1050i8100...."

output: [2080,1050,8100,...]
Could anyone help me?

Comment: you forgot to post your [attempt](https://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/) for this problem.

Comment: will you only have `f` and `r` in between the digits, or is it a case of any alphabetic characters could be used?

Comment: The `re` module is *part* of vanilla Python. Is there some reason you can't import *built-in* modules? What *else* can't you do?

Answer (score 3):

Try:

```py
out = list(
    map(int, "".join(ch if "0" <= ch <= "9" else " " for ch in x).split())
)
print(out)
```

Prints:

```py
[100, 90, 100]
```

---

EDIT: Version without `map()`:

```py
out = [
    int(num)
    for num in "".join(ch if "0" <= ch <= "9" else " " for ch in x).split()
]
print(out)
```

Comment: @dgfrlab I've added version without `map()`

Answer (score 2):

A slightly roundabout way, but still within the bounds of "vanilla" Python:

> Note: `string` is a builtin module, but there are various alternatives to this. For example, you could use `str.isdigit()` or check the [ascii value](https://python-reference.readthedocs.io/en/latest/docs/str/ASCII.html) like `48 <= ord(c) <= 57`.

```py
import string

_is_num = set(string.digits).__contains__


def get_digits(s):  # type: (str) -> list[int]
    digits = []
    num_start = False
    i_start = 0

    for i, c in enumerate(s):  # type: int, str
        if num_start:
            if not _is_num(c):
                num_start = False
                digits.append(int(s[i_start:i]))
        elif _is_num(c):
            num_start = True
            i_start = i

    if num_start:
        digits.append(int(s[i_start:]))

    return digits
```

Usage:

```py
x = "f100r90f100e300"
print(get_digits(x))  # [100, 90, 100, 300]
```

Answer (score 1):

To improve on Andrej's answer:

```
out = list(
    map(int, "".join(ch if ch.isdigit() else " " for ch in x).split())
)
print(out)
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope this "vanilla" enough:

```
x = "f100r90f100"

tmp = []
for i in x:
    if i.isdigit():
        tmp.append(i)
    else:
        tmp.append(" ")

tmp = "".join(tmp).split()

xlist = []
for i in tmp:
    xlist.append(int(i))

print(xlist)

# [100, 90, 100]
```